# Export To Excel a div content using Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to export div data which using JavaScript. It is exported to Excel but without css. No border is showing in Excel format, even I am not able to give name of Excel file.

Here is my code:

```
function ExportToExcel() {
    var contents = $(".divclass").html();
    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(contents));
}
```

Comment: and your div is composed of?

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#btnExport").click(function(e) {
  let file = new Blob([$('.divclass').html()], {type:"application/vnd.ms-excel"});
let url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
let a = $("<a />", {
  href: url,
  download: "filename.xls"}).appendTo("body").get(0).click();
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation, please?

Comment: @BartoszT - We create the file and add it as a link on the page. For example, I have already done it . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45253672/how-do-i-export-a-form-table-in-excel-file-format-using-javascript

Comment: Hey , this is best answer i have seen so far. Thanks